Choosing maximum number of unique and valid combinations
For the past few days I have been trying to find an algorithm that will help me find the maximum number of unique combinations based on the list of approved combinations.
Each combination is a set of 1..n elements (elements must not repeat) defined beforehand.
E.g.
List of elements (contains the number of available pieces):



Element
Quantity




A
2


B
3


C
2


D
4


E
2


F
3



List of approved combinations (one occurrence of an element means that 1 piece of that element is needed):



Combination
Elements




C1
A, C, D


C2
C, D, F


C3
E, A


C4
A, F, C



Out of above, I can choose {C1, C4} or {C1, C2, C3}.
And now having a list of combinations, I would like to optimize which combinations to choose in order to use as many of them (unique!) as possible having only the elements from the list and only in such quantity, i.e. choose {C1, C4} instead {C1, C2, C3}.
I tried the "greedy" algorithm, i.e., checking the combinations one by one as long as there were enough elements, but the results were far from ideal. ChatGPT was also not helpful.
Will someone help with a piece of code (Java or any other language) or at least the name of the algorithm, so that I can look further (I assume that such a problem is already named ;) )?

You can also choose {C1}, {C2}, {C3}, {C4}, {C1, C2}, {C1, C3} and many more combinations.  Then you talk about optimization: considering the exponential nature of the problem, I guess it is a NP-hard problem, so no greedy algorithm will solve it for you.

The general problem you're looking to solve here is a generalisation of (that is, it's harder than) a well-known problem called Set Cover. Unfortunately Set Cover is NP-complete, which means in practical terms that no one knows a "good" algorithm to solve it optimally on all problem instances. The best algorithms known for NP-complete problems are all of the "generate every possibility and see if it's the best so far" variety, so they take time exponential in some aspect of the input (typically the number of valid combinations, or the number of element types).
If the problem instances you're working on are very small, like in your example, simply trying all combinations will work fine. This should only take a few milliseconds for your example problem, and is probably feasible for up to around 20 different combinations (C1, ..., C20).
The simplest approach for your specific problem is to loop over all possible subsets of combinations, for each subset testing whether it can be satisfied by the quantities of elements you have available. If there are n combinations, there are 2^n possible subsets of them (so 2^4 = 16 possible subsets for your example), and you can use the bits in an integer to enumerate them easily: just use an integer loop variable that runs from 0 to 2^n-1, and use bit 0 (the rightmost) to represent whether C1 is included, bit 1 to represent whether C2 is included, and so on.

That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for confirmation.
